# Difference between two timestamp in seconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am creating certain table rows dynamically using jquery , I want to display created ago in seconds in that row, I tried below code

```
var currenttime = moment();
$(".tbody").append("<tr><td class='tdata' data-id='"+currenttime+"'>0 seconds</td></tr>");


setInterval(function(){ 
var latest = moment();
var oldtime = $(".tdata").data("id");
var newtime = oldtime-latest;
$(".tdata").html(newtime+ "secs");
}, 3000);
```

So basically i am storing current time while row creation and then checking randomly and displaying the total seconds (not minutes or hours) , if 5 mins it should display 300.

I tried var later = moment(); , but it creates object i cannot store it in data-attribute , it will be great even if it can be done without momentjs , any ideas please , thnank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need moment here but just [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) ([getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method)

```
var currenttime = new Date().getTime(); // Count milliseconds since 1970
$(".tbody").append("<tr><td class='tdata' data-id='"+currenttime+"'>0 seconds</td></tr>");


setInterval(function(){ 
  var oldtime = parseInt($(".tdata").data("id")); // HTML store it as String, don't forget to transform it to int "14254782000" > 14254782000
  var seconds = parseInt((new Date().getTime() - oldtime) / 1000);
  $(".tdata").html(seconds+ " secs");
}, 1000);
```

This way you're not storing a moment object but a number of seconds (int), also it's always Now - Past (and not Past - Now) because Now is higher than Past (and we want a positive value).

Comment: hi , its showing random numbers like 400 ,42321 , 113404 every seconds , should i divide it by 1000 or something ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot than getTime return in millisecond (so yes you have to divide by 1000).

Comment: (Answer udated to handle millisecond)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what to explain about this example:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("tbody").append("<tr><td class='tdata'><span data-seconds-since=" + Date.now() + ">0</span> seconds</td></tr>");
});

// updates all places at once
setInterval(function(){ 
  var now = Date.now();
  $("[data-seconds-since]").text(function(){
    return ((now - this.dataset.secondsSince) / 1000).toFixed(1)
  });
}, 40);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table><tbody></tbody></table>

<button type="button">Add Row</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Little change

```
var starts = Date.now();
//...
var diff = (Date.now() - starts) / 10000;
```

You can also check [moment.duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) since your already using momentJS.